# Find the critical points (minimum, maximum and saddle) of several variable function

Tags: optimization, special-functions, nonlinear-optimization

I'm trying to minimize and maximize the following function:
$$f(x_1,x_2)=x_1^2+x_2^2-\cos(18x_1)-\cos(18x_2).$$

The problem is that I have to find all the critical points but I don't know how to solve without using the computer the equations of the gradient vector.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You should choose your tags carefully. What has this to do with `special-functions`?

Comment: Well, why do you think there's a closed-form solution?  It looks to me like it has to solved numerically.

Comment: At first I thought that @saulspatz. But the final question was that how many critical points there were of each. That made me doubt. Thanks!!